# MSTest 2012 - Run all tests in project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

Looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i can see that I can;

Run a specific test, run tests in specific categories, or run tests defined in a *.TestSettings.

Is there anyway I can just run *all* tests within the project without explicitly setting groups/lists/tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:{ProjectBinFolder}\TestProject.dll
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679966/what-command-line-arguments-does-visual-studio-use-for-running-mstest/10751484#10751484). I think there is no difference between vs2010 & vs2012.