# Coded Ui - Run ordered test using MStest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I've multiple ordered test in test project.
How can i run specific ordered test using MStest.

I'm Using below syntax for running any specific test.

MSTest /testcontainer:"**dll path**" /test:"**testname**"

but it doesn't work for Ordered test.

Answer (score 0):

`MSTest.exe /testcontainer:LoadTest1.loadtest /testcontainer:OrderedTest1.orderedtest`

reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679966/what-command-line-arguments-does-visual-studio-use-for-running-mstest)