# MSTests fail at command line, but work in Visual Studio 2017 IDE

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to configure a command line build using the command line.

I have Visual Studio 2017 installed on Windows Server 2016.

I have installed all the build tools and they seem to work.

When I run my MSTest unit tests in Visual Studio 2017 IDE they all pass.

When I run them at the command line some pass and some fail.

Can someone tell me what might be wrong or how to figure it out? Normally when a test fails it fails in the IDE so I can debug it. In this case I can't debug it because it passes.

Comment: What command are you running on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vstest.console.exe` to run your tests. `mstest.exe` exists solely for backwards compatibility.

See the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms182486(v=vs.140)) for more info.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had no idea that MSTest was outdated. Thanks!